# Find First and Last day of quarter using Function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dtqrtr(generationDate DATE)
RETURN DATE
IS
    dquery DATE;
BEGIN
    dquery := TRUNC(TO_DATE (generationDate),'YEAR');
    dquery := TRUNC(TO_DATE ( generationDate),'Q');
    dbms_output.put_line ('First_Quarter : ' || dquery || '   '||'Last_Quarter : ' || add_months(dquery -1,3));
END dquery;

END dtqrtr;

SELECT dtqrtr('20-JAN-2015')
FROM DUAL;
```

I want the year and first and last day of quarter. But I receive the error message:

> **ORA-06575:** Package or function DTQRTR is in an invalid state

Comment: Hmmm, if only we knew what the error message was ...

Comment: ORA-06575: Package or function DTQRTR is in an invalid state
It is the error messege

Comment: That's the error you get when you run the `SELECT` query. The problem with the function is something else. I suggest you execute the `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` again, then (assuming you're using SQLPlus) type `SHOW ERRORS FUNCTION DTQRTR`; this will show you the compilation errors which resulted from the most recent compilation of this function. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

`ORA-06575` means that your function was compiled with errors. Very probably there is some syntax error in your function code. From SQL*Plus (and some other tools) you can display the error by using:

```
SHOW ERROR;
```

or

```
SHOW ERROR FUNCTION dtqrtr;
```

Here, my *guess* is you have too many `END` statements... and, as noticed by Ben in a comment bellow, a *function* has to return a value. Finally, it is rather strange too that you put something into `dquery` in the first line of the body, to overwrite it the next line.

Comment: Yes, that , plus a function has to return something.

Comment: @Ben Yes, that is correct. I think the OP wrote `end dquery` instead of `return dquery`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dtqrtr(generationDate DATE)
RETURN DATE
IS
    dquery DATE;
BEGIN
    dquery := TRUNC(TO_DATE (generationDate),'YEAR');
    dquery := TRUNC(TO_DATE ( generationDate),'Q');
    dbms_output.put_line ('First_Quarter : ' || dquery || '   '||'Last_Quarter : ' || add_months(dquery -1,3));
    RETURN dquery;
END dtqrtr;
/

SELECT dtqrtr('20-JAN-2015')
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: This code has no return value.....type RETURN(dquery) before               END dtqrtr;   I solve the problem but this return type show only one value what should I do to get multiple value

Comment: @user3722544 - please don't ask additional questions in comments - and don't go back and edit this question to include a second question. If you have another question, please post another question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want two values: the first day of the quarter and the last day of the quarter.  This is a poor fit for a function, which can only return a single value.  However, both values are easily derivable with built-in SQL functions:

```
with cte as ( select date '2015-01-20' dt from dual )
select trunc(dt, 'Q') as qtr_st
       , last_day(add_months(trunc(dt, 'Q'),2)) as qtr_end
from cte
/
```

You might consider wrapping those three calls for QTR_END in a user-defined function, but it's probably only worthwhile if you're going to do this call a lot.